# Разбираю пример из книги. Все равно получаю ошибку

Tags: python-3.x, классы

Вот такой код (пример из книги, набран вручную):

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def move(self, delta_x, delta_y):
        self.x = self.x + delta_x
        self.y = self.y + delta_y


class Circle(Shape):
    pi = 3.14159
    all_circles = []
    def __init__(self, r=0, x=0, y=0):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.radius = r
        all_circles.append(self)


c1 = Circle()
print(c1.radius, c1.x, c1.y)
```

В 17-й строке - all_circles.append(self) - компилятор подчеркивает волнистой линией и выдает такую ошибку:

**NameError: name 'all_circles' is not defined**

Текст перенабрал вручную, а не копипастил, чтобы не было недоразумений. Все равно такая ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> all_circles.append(self)
> ```

```
Circle.all_circles.append(self)
```

Comment: либо `self.all_circles.append(self)` , с тем же результатом

Comment: @SergFSM Это до тех пор, пока экземпляр не переопределит `self.all_curcles`, он теоретически может это сделать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, справедливо.

Comment: Спасибо всем. Отметил вопрос как решенный.
После этого решил поискать, как такое могло произойти. Нашел. Действительно, в книге, допущены опечатки. И эта - одна из них. 
Может кому-то будет интересно название книги:
Наоми Седер - Python. Экспресс курс (3-е издание)